# Laravel Eloquent : Set custom formatted ID in Table

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Is there any way where I can add custom formatted ID on create?

for example, there is a table 'Customers', in this table there are one primary key - 'ID (auto increment)' and one unique key 'customer_id'

Now, when I will create a new customer, the 'ID' is auto increment so it will automatically set in DB.

I want to set 'customer_id' like '2018-0001' at the time of create.
CurrentYear-000 INSERTED_ID

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) In order to get better answers and to avoid downvotes, please share what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `created` model event for this. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events)

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into the
>   following points in a model's lifecycle: `retrieved`, `creating`, `created`,
>   `updating`, `updated`, `saving`, `saved`, `deleting`,  `deleted`, `restoring`,
>   `restored`. Events allow you to easily execute code each time a specific
>   model class is saved or updated in the database. Each event receives
>   the instance of the model through its constructor.

After creating the `customer` you could generate the `customer_id` and save it:

**Customer.php**

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
       parent::boot();

       static::created(function ($obj) {
          $obj->customer_id = Carbon::now()->year.'-000'.$obj->id;
          $obj->save();
      });
    }
}
```